# HTML/Javascript reverse progress bar with countdown date

Tags: javascript, date, progress-bar, reverse, countdown

I can't seem to find something that creates a progress bar emptying while it comes close to the countdown date.

I found two separate examples that could be combined but I don't know how to:
**Countdown** - https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Minimal-jQuery-Any-Date-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-countdown.html (1st example, SIMPLE TEXT COUNTDOWN)
**Progress bar** - https://jsfiddle.net/zessx/4PKEB/1/:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
 var progressBarWidth = (timeleft / timetotal) * $element.width();
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};
progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));
});
</script>

<style>
#progressBar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
    width: 0;
    background-color: #CBEA00;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>

<div id="progressBar">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE QUESTION**
Let me explain a little more what i need.
I need to combine the code from both links and get something like this:
[image]
So what I finally need is to have the countdown text (circled in blue), to actually correspond to the decreasing color (circled in red) in the progress bar.
In few words I want a progress bar with text in it counting days, hours, minutes, seconds upto a specific date not for a specific amount of time.

My entire html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown Plugin Examples</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Any-Date-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-countdown/dest/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var endDate = "December 31, 2088 23:59:59";

    $('.countdown.simple').countdown({ date: endDate });

    // End time for diff purposes
    var endTimeDiff = new Date().getTime() + 15000;
    // This is server's time
    var timeThere = new Date();
    // This is client's time (delayed)
    var timeHere = new Date(timeThere.getTime() - 5434);
    // Get the difference between client time and server time
    var diff_ms = timeHere.getTime() - timeThere.getTime();
    // Get the rounded difference in seconds
    var diff_s = diff_ms / 1000 | 0;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
        //var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
        var progressBarWidth = (timeleft / timetotal) * $element.width();
        $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear');
        if(timeleft > 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
    progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));
});
</script>

<style>
body {
    font: 13px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica','Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
.container {
    width: 520px;
    margin: auto;
}
h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
h2{
    position: relative;;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2:before{
    content: '\2192';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
a {
    color: #be2221;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.simple {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #27ae60;
    padding: 0.5em 0.7em;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
}
.simple {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.simple div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
/* IE7 inline-block hack */
*+html .simple div {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
.simple div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.simple div span {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#progressBar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#progressBar div {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
    width: 0;
    background-color: #CBEA00;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <h2>Simple text countdown</h2>
    <div class="countdown simple" data-date="December 31, 2018 23:59:59"></div>

    <div id="progressBar">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I know its kinda late to answer but this is just in case someone else needs this with starting and ending date.

based on **Lowell Ed Llames** answer:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {

        let days = parseInt(timeleft / 86400);
        let hoursLeft = parseInt(timeleft - days * 86400);
        let hours = parseInt(hoursLeft / 3600);
        let minutesLeft = parseInt(hoursLeft - hours * 3600);
        let minutes = parseInt(minutesLeft / 60);
        let seconds = parseInt(timeleft % 60);

        let progressBarWidth = timeleft / timetotal * $element.width();

        $element
        .find("div")
        .css('width', progressBarWidth );
        $('.timeleft').html(
         `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} seconds`);
        if (timeleft > 0)
        setTimeout(() => progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element), 1000);
    }

    // Starting Date
    let dateStart = new Date('2021-03-10');

    // Ending Date
    let dateEnd   = new Date('2021-03-20');

    // Current Date
    let dateNow   = new Date('2021-03-17');

    let timetotal = (dateEnd.getTime() / 1000) - (dateStart.getTime() / 1000);
    let timeleft  = (dateEnd.getTime() / 1000) - (dateNow.getTime() / 1000);

    progress(timeleft, timetotal, $("#progressBar"));
 });
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #ececee;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#progressBar div {
   height: 100%;
   text-align: right;
   padding: 0;    /* remove padding */
   line-height: 22px;
   width: 0;
   background-color: #7ac843;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Any-Date-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-countdown/dest/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
  
<p>Time left: <span class="timeleft"></span></p>
<div id="progressBar">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ill add this as an answer instead of a comment:

instead of calculating upwards, subtract the progress from the total:

```
var totalTime = 100;
var currentTime = 15;
var timeRemaining = totalTime - currentTime;
var progressPCT = (currentTime / totalTime ) * 100;
var remaningProgressPCT = 100 - progressPCT; 
console.log("Time Remaining: ", timeRemaining);
console.log("Progress Bar Fill: ", remainingProgressPCT);
```

then put the variable remaningProgressPCT as the progress on your bar?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain it very well, my english is poor and I'm sorry for that.
Changing the progress bar code into what you suggest, I get the opposite visual result form what I need.
I need it the way it already reacts. Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 1):

First at your script

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = (timeleft / timetotal) * $element.width(); //<-- refactor the formula

 // your codes
};
```

then styles:

```
#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;    /* remove padding */
  line-height: 22px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

### UPDATE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    let progressBarWidth = timeleft / timetotal * $element.width();

    let days = parseInt(timeleft / 86400);
    let hoursLeft = parseInt(timeleft - days * 86400);
    let hours = parseInt(hoursLeft / 3600);
    let minutesLeft = parseInt(hoursLeft - hours * 3600);
    let minutes = parseInt(minutesLeft / 60);
    let seconds = parseInt(timeleft % 60);

    $element
      .find("div")
      .animate(
        { width: progressBarWidth },
        timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000,
        "linear"
      )
      .html(
        `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} seconds`
      );
    if (timeleft > 0)
      setTimeout(() => progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element), 1000);
  }
  progress(60, 60, $("#progressBar"));
});
```

```css
body {
    font: 13px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica','Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
.container {
    width: 520px;
    margin: auto;
}
h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
h2{
    position: relative;;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2:before{
    content: '\2192';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
a {
    color: #be2221;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.simple {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #27ae60;
    padding: 0.5em 0.7em;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
}
.simple {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.simple div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
/* IE7 inline-block hack */
*+html .simple div {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
.simple div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.simple div span {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#progressBar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;    /* remove padding */
  line-height: 22px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Any-Date-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-countdown/dest/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

  <div id="progressBar">
      <div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for. Now the text is transfered inside the second row, the color is correctly decreasing in the progress bar but when the page is refreshed the countdown starts over again. I want it to count days, hours, minutes, seconds for a specific date not a specific amount of time. Thanks again for your time!!!